# Mailchimp INTERESTED merge tag advanced conditions

Tags: if-statement, merge, conditional-statements, mailchimp

I have read ALL on mailchimp website from all api docs to blog comments :D
and even talked (chat) with there support.
Support helped me in some why but nothing i didnt knew :D
Merge tags have IF and ELSEIF statements and work on OR logic there is NO AND !!!
A bit blaaahhhhh if you ask me... ;)
(Mailchimp add AND) XD
So i have a question if anyone tried this.
I have one List with 2 Groups 
(Group title: Categories
with Group names: language course, IT course, first aid course, cooking course;

Group title: Cities
with Group names: New York, Washington, Springfield, Texas)

And i want to send campaign to users who have this criteria:
Categories:IT course
OR AND
Cities: New York

i have tried:

```
 
|INTERESTED:Categories:IT course|
  |INTERESTED:Cities:New York|
    (STEP 1) This text will print only to New York & IT Course Subscribers;
  |END:INTERESTED:|
  This text will print only to IT Course Subscribers;
     BUT if they already are receiving from step ONE (STEP 1)
     This will duplicate the msg
|END:INTERESTED:|
```

So i tried this:
*|INTERESTED:Categories:IT course|*
  *|INTERESTED:Cities:New York|*
    (STEP 1) This text will print only to New York & IT Course Subscribers;
  *|END:INTERESTED:|*
*|ELSE:|*
     BUT this is okey :D but what if they dont have IT course selected
     where will the "Cities:New York" message print ??? SOOO.... next step xD
*|END:INTERESTED:|*

It should be something like this. Right?
*|INTERESTED:Categories:IT course|*
  *|INTERESTED:Cities:New York|*
    (STEP 1) This text will print only to New York & IT Course Subscribers;
  *|END:INTERESTED:|*
*|ELSE:|*
  *|INTERESTED:Categories:IT course|*
    (STEP 2) This text will print only to IT course Subscribers;
  *|END:INTERESTED:|*
*|ELSE:|*
  *|INTERESTED:Cities:New York|*
    (STEP 3) This text will print only to New York Subscribers;
         and this gets duplicated but it shouldnt even get executed
  *|END:INTERESTED:|*
*|END:INTERESTED:|*

AND COMPLEX step
What if i have one Categories and two Cities

```
 
|INTERESTED:Categories:IT course|
  |INTERESTED:Cities:New York, Washington|
    (STEP 1) This text will print only to New York, Washington & IT Course Subscribers;
  |END:INTERESTED:|
*|END:INTERESTED:|*
how to do this one ???
:D
```

I think this is possible but i cant find any mistakes in nesting.
I hope you have better idea and NESTING plan ;)

And did anyone tried *|IF:|* on *|INTERESTED:...|*
a have seen in doc. that there is *|ELSE|* clause but not *|IF|* nor *|ELSEIF|* so i asked the support and they told me to try it (my conclusion THEY DONT KNOW) where i was very surprised, so i tried it and of course the syntax is wrong.
What did i tried?
few variations:
this is the right syntax (normal)
*|INTERESTED:...|*
*|END:INTERESTED:|*

*|INTERESTED:...|*
...
*|ELSE:|*
...
*|END:INTERESTED:|*
.
.
.

i have tried:
*|IF:INTERESTED:...|*
...
*|ELSEIF:|*
...
*|END:INTERESTED:|*

and

*|IF:INTERESTED:...|*
...
*|ELSEIF:|*
...
*|ENDIF:|*

because i didnt know what to close INTERESTED merge tag or IF merge tag
i got some gibberish but i think somethig is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution if anyone is interested here it is :D

```
|INTERESTED:Categories: IT course>|
    |INTERESTED:Cities: New York|
        Categories: IT course & Cities: New York were selected
    |ELSE:|
        |INTERESTED:Categories: IT course|
            this is because if you dont find users
            with Categories: IT course & Cities: New York
        |END:INTERESTED|
    |END:INTERESTED|
*|ELSE:|*
    |INTERESTED:Cities: New York|
        This will print if Categories: IT course were FALSE
    |END:INTERESTED|
*|END:INTERESTED|*
```

But now i have different question, it involves all of this.
How can now SKIP sending email to person who doesnt have anything select ???
:D
My friend suggested to try with segments and API but i would also like to hear from other people.

Comment: Make that a new question -- but the easiest way is to use the "segment" feature (only send to folks who have the group categories.. no need for api level work

Answer (score 1):

Clarification: Are you trying: 1) to create a segment to send a campaign to; or 2) Cause particular information to appear in a campaign depending on which groups the subscriber is in?

Here is what you can use to control what text appears within a campaign

```
*|INTERESTED:Categories:IT course|*
  *|INTERESTED::Cities:New York|*This text will appear only if category is "IT Course" and cities is "New York"
  *|ELSE:|*This text will appear only if category is "IT Course" and cities is not "New York"
  *|END:INTERESTED|*
*|ELSE:|*This text will appear only if category is not "IT Course"
*|END:INTERESTED|*
```

You can nest both Group inclusion (INTERESTED ... END:INTERESTED) and regular field IF:field= and END:IF sections